# What is the print server? on minimal install

Tags: unity, 18.04

So, I am thinking of making an instructional on how to install Ubuntu with unity from minimal installer.. and i was wondering about the necessity of installing the printserver package at the installer. The reason why i did this before is because of an instructional I earlier saw, but I can't remember why I would need to do so.

So my question is frankly: Do I need to install the printserver when installing ubuntu from mini, or does this install with `ubuntu-unity-desktop` package?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine a package's dependencies?

Comment: that might be the right way to say it, but I'm not sure what that means.. basically, while installing from the net-installer, can i leave all the fields blank when it asks me to install servers, desktops etc. and then later install unity?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu is modular - you can easily add services as you discover a need for them.